# Inductance calc for Edge Coupled Differential Pair?

Tags: differential, inductance, microstrip

Apologies up front if this topic has been addressed. I've searched on StackExchange and am concluding that this structure is uncommon as there is no ground return accompanying the differential pair shown below.

I'm hoping to find an inductance calc for Cu on a substrate (substrate thickness approx 25 um):

`++++++++++++++++++     -------------------
       <- 25 um thick substrate ->`

* +/- is to show this is a diff pair with length running in/out of screen

* thickness of each strip is <= 1 um

* separation between the strips is >> thickness

* width of each strip is > separation

Even a crude calculation would help.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the material above and below the traces the same or different?

Comment: And what is beneath the 25-um substrate?

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete diagram. It can be assumed that the strips are embedded within the substrate midway between top and bottom. If it helps then consider the strips to be sandwiched between two 12.5 um substrate layers. Thanks!

Comment: I've found an analysis of busbars here: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9780470772874.app1/pdf where I see this equation that may be suited to my needs:

Comment: You can use an edge-coupled strip-line calculator and just increase the h parameter toward infinity. But if the result depends strongly on h when h ~ 25 um, then you know you will be subject to disturbance from nearby objects.

Comment: sorry - the equation wouldn't copy-paste. it is on p484 of the reference cited above

Comment: Sure. [Try this one](http://wcalc.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/coupled_stripline.cgi), by the way.

Comment: actually, large h is the wrong assumption so don't want to extend it to infinity since h << separation. i realize i left that important point out. separation will be at least 20 x h.

Comment: H isn't really the thickness of the substrate, it's the distance away from any nearby metal (that would act like a ground plane). If h << s, then if there is metal anywhere near your system it will mess up the behavior.

Comment: got it. yes, it's a good assumption that there will be no metal nearby relative to width of the strips (i.e. h >> width). Thanks!

Comment: The fact that you don't have uniform dielectric above and below means you won't get an accurate characteristic impedance or capacitance calculation from the basic calculator. But the inductance calculation shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: good news is that I know the capacitance with some accuracy. thanks again The Photon!

Comment: i found this at the same site you pointed me to: http://wcalc.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/bars.cgi

Answer (score 2):

You clearly have a what appears to be coplanar waveguide, or a truly banced pair which require no reference.

The coplanar waveguide is the only controlled impedance structure that does not require a plane beneath it apart from a truly balanced pair.

Is there a reference on the same layer as the the differential pair?

Comment: Coplanar waveguide would have reference on both sides of the signal trace. And usually a different dielectric above and below. The drawing initially made me think "slot line", but it sounds like OP actually has the same dielectric for 25 um above and below the lines, then some other material (air?) beyond that. I doubt if there will be an off-the shelf simulation for this.

Comment: Updated with potential of truly balsnced pair